# Adding a chart to a view and render it

Tags: android, achartengine

If i set a Chart as content view everythings works fine:

```
GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context,dataset,renderer);
setContentView(mChartView);
```

But if I add the `GraphicalView` to a view the chart isn't rendered:

```
GraphicalView mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context,dataset,renderer);
ScrollView sView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.sview);
sView.add(mChartView);
```

Is there a way to get the chart rendered even if it isn't the content view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to create a layout in your `ScrollView` and add the `mChartView` to it like this

```
 layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

It work fine for me so ...